# Tweaking location of zoomControl (cartodb.js)

Tags: leaflet, carto

I have succeeded in creating a header outside of the CartoDB UI, but the header is blocking the zoom controls, as can be seen below.

[image]

Is there any way to modify the zoom control location to adapt to the existence of this header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use CSS on `.leaflet-top` class to adjust the `top` positioning of all Leaflet controls:

```css
.leaflet-top {
  top: 100px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/196/

Answer (score 2):

Set zoomControl to false when you init the map, then add it to a different corner:

```js
// initiate leaflet map
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 2,
    zoomControl: false
})
// add zoomControl
L.control.zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(map);
```